# Raspberry pi weather station dampness

Tags: pi-2, sensor, pi-zero

I am setting up a rpi weather station with several rpi 0's (one for each sensor) and a main rpi 2 (for the data collection and storage). Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about damp proofing my pi's? I live in the UK so it's quite rainy most of the time. They are under a roof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/85511/5538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is [3M's Novec 1700 electronic coating](https://www.3m.co.uk/3M/en_GB/novec-uk/applications/device-component-coatings/)... but it may not be available in the UK, in a form and quantity suitable for hobbyist usage. Failing that, a more conventional conformal coating will improve things some, and make your boards more resistant to the effects of moisture - [here's one available from a UK distributor](https://uk.farnell.com/servisol/100009000/coating-spray-plastic-200ml/dp/3821407?CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-3821407&CAGPSPN=pla&gross_price=true&CAWELAID=120173390000317142&CATCI=pla-298937144115&CAAGID=14406255429), or a [somewhat better, although more expensive product](https://uk.farnell.com/electrolube/lfcc400ml/coating-conformal-lead-free/dp/1098274?CMP=KNC-GUK-GEN-SHOPPING-1098274&CAGPSPN=pla&gross_price=true&CAWELAID=120173390000242569&CATCI=pla-300605519919&CAAGID=14406255429).

If you're keen on doing a bit of reading and research on some details of conformal coating, this [Wikipedia article is a fair place to begin.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_coating)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the links you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how permanent you want to make your set up this might work:
 [Circuit protected by a brick of clear resin](https://hackaday.com/2012/04/13/free-formed-circuit-protected-by-a-brick-of-crystal-clear-resin/)

Encasing everything in clear resin will keep the damp out, your sensors will probably need to be exposed or very near the surface?

Comment: They will need to be near the surface for things like the temperature and humidity sensor. However I will need to have some wires going outside for the wind speed and direction sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Small Waterproof ”Tough Box" Dry Box for First Aid Kits, Survival Kits and valuables [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074L1Y897/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_f8LYBb67EB6VR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074L1Y897)

I use these with some cable glands. I've had one outside for over a year. Rain, snow, sun. Still working.